# How do I create a total at the bottom for VAT items and NON VAT items?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[Pcture of Form I want to update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qkvJ.jpg)I use an excel spreadsheet to calculate an order total.

There are the following columns -

- Quantity
- Item Price
- VAT Code,  (1 being "add vat", 2 being "non vat" and 3 being
  "including vat")
- Line Net Total
- Line VAT Total

Once I input figures in the quantity, price and vat code  the other two columns are calculated. There is then a subtotal of each of these last two columns at the bottom of the sheet plus an overall total.
I wish to create a total at the bottom for VAT items and NON VAT items so need to add another column with a formula that says -

IF (cell containing vat code = 1 or 3 add the net total column and vat column together but if the vat code is 2 do nothing and leave it at 0 but not sure how to write this formula

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Although there are some answers, please keep in mind there is a reasonable expectation that you have attempted something before asking here. So, if you could complete your post with additional details of what you have tried, we can better understand where you are at in the process of resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

Say VAT Code is C2 and VAT Total is F2 - then G2 - sum if VAT - would go `=IF(OR(C2=1,C2=3),F2,0)`

Then you sum the whole G column, where rows with VAT Code other than 1 or 3 are 0, rest F2.

Your question is very hard to understand - you'd best show some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have...

`A2` - Quantity
`B2` - Item Price
`C2` - VAT Code
`D2` - Line Net Total
`E2` - VAT
`F2` - Line VAT Total
`G2` - Line Non VAT Total

and VAT is 20%

You need

`E2` formula to be `=IF(C2=1,D2*20%,0)`
`F2` formula to be `=IF(OR(C2=1,C2=3),D2+E2,"")`
`G2` formula to be `=IF(C2=2,B2,"")`

`SUM` column `F` for total VAT Items
`SUM` column `G` for total Non VAT Items